# Am I hitting a thread limit?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have the following working code to get a stream from a url:

```
private Stream GetDownloadStream(string url)
{
    Stream stream = null;

    AutoResetEvent downloadCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    httpRequest.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
    httpRequest.BeginGetResponse(
        result =>
        {
            try
            {
                httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(result);
                stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                downloadCompleted.Set();
                Abort();
            }
            finally
            {
                downloadCompleted.Set();
            }
        },
        null);

    bool completed = downloadCompleted.WaitOne(15 * 1000);
    if (completed) {
        return stream;
    }
    return null;
}
```

It doesn't matter the streams I choose to play. It always returns a stream for the first 6 requests and it returns null on the seven request.

I already tried to increase the timeout to 30 seconds but on the seventh request it won't enter on the `httpRequest.BeginGetResponse` callback.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, but a limit on the OS seems quite reasonable! Remember: this is a mobile device with limited battery, memory, processing capacity and (usually) an internet plan paid per Kb!!

Comment: I assume that you are using Visual Studio. If so, you can see which threads are running by pausing the application and opening the threads windows. (I'm not on my Windows PC so can't tell you the exact name and how to get to this window). I've dealt with threading issues before, and from what I remember you have 1 GUI/main thread, and 25 background threads. It sounds like you should have enough to do this task. Check how many threads are currently running in your app and let us know if you're using them all up. Otherwise it's another issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting the limit on the number of concurrent web requests (which is 6).

Try closing the stream when you've finished with it or staggering your requests so that you're not trying to make too many at once.

Comment: I was Closing and Disposing the stream and Closing the httpResponse. I just forgot to Abort the WebRequest. Thanks